# Warning: Undefined array key in php for unknown reason

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Hello everyone
 I was practicing php arrays and my editor cannot detect an error I have with my php however when it runs I get the error message

> Warning: Undefined array key 3 in php

while still printing the output correctly. 
 my html form is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Number of Students</title></head>
        <body>
            <form action="Q4.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of Students:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="num" size="5"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

my php form is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>Number of Students</title></head>
        <body>
            <form action="Q4index.php">
            <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
                <tr><th>Student</th><th>Mark</th></tr>
            <?php
            $num = $_GET["num"];
            for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++){
            echo"<tr><td><input type=text name=stud[] size=7></td>
            <td><input type=text name=mark[] size=5></td></tr>";
            }
            ?>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td><td><input type="Reset" value="Reset"</td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and the php program file to run it all is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title></title></head>
        <body>
            <h3>The students who passed the exam:</h3>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                <tr><th>Name</th><th>Total Mark</th></tr>
            <?php
            //Declaration of Arrays
            $name=$_GET["stud"];
            $mark=$_GET["mark"];
            //Loop and Conditions
            for($i=0; $i<=count($name); $i++){ 
                if($mark[$i]>=50){
            //Printing        
                echo"<tr><td>$name[$i]</td><td>$mark[$i]</td></tr>";}
            }
            ?>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

After entering sample data in the forms and trying to execute the code this error message appears:
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfjn2.png)

Can someone please tell me what my code is missing? Thank you in advance and I'm beyond grateful for your patience with my questions :)

Comment: Please, always show us ALL the error message. they have filenames and line numbers that help to identify the location of the error and they are text, so post as tect not pictures pelase

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($name); $i++){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the heads up I will take note of it from now on :)

Comment: Please post the error as text!  See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove '=' in condition "$i<=count($name)".
Write "$i < count($name)".